# How do I configure The Business Data Connectivity Service Application?

Tags: external-content-type

I'm currently trying to add an external content type. In order to do this I've read that I need the Business Data Connectivity service running. I have tried Provisioning the service but it ends up in error(Refer to PIC1). When trying to access the service I get an error message displayed that states "The load balancer is not provisioned."(Refer to PIC2)
[image: PIC1]
[image: PIC2]

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you tried deleting the service from central admin, and re-adding it?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps to configure BDC, if already created then delete it and re-add it by given steps:

1. Central Administration -> Go to Service Applications ->  Manage Service Applications -> Select Business Data Connectivity -> choose Delete from the ribbon.
2. From the same page select "New" from the ribbon, and chose "Business Data Connectivity" from the list it provided and create it.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683108.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try Deleting the service from central administration and recreate it.

This will re provision what you require.

Refer the following link for more information,

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f60259f6-72db-461c-940b-7d81ccf1b50d/business-data-connectivity-the-load-balancer-is-not-provisioned?forum=sharepointadminprevious